# PHP Array - Finding Closest Date

Tags: php

Working on a small formula to find the closet date from a number of dates stored in an array. I can get this working with hardcoded dates, but not using PHP Variables, any ideas?

```
<?php
                $dates = array
                (
                    '0'=> date('Y-m-d', $Date1),
                    '1'=> date('Y-m-d', $Date2),
                    '2'=> date('Y-m-d', $Date3),
                    '3'=> date('Y-m-d', $Date4),
                    '4'=> date('Y-m-d', $Date5),
                    '5'=> date('Y-m-d', $Date6),
                    '6'=> date('Y-m-d', $Date7),
                    '7'=> date('Y-m-d', $Date8)
                );

                function closes($dates, $findate)
                {
                    $newDates = array();

                    foreach($dates as $date)
                    {
                        $newDates[] = strtotime($date);
                    }

                    sort($newDates);
                    foreach ($newDates as $a)
                    {
                        if ($a >= strtotime($findate)) return $a;
                    }
                    return end($newDates);
                }


                $values = closes($dates, date('Y-m-d'));

                ?>
                <h3>Next Date</h3><br/>
                <?php echo date('l, F jS, Y',$values); 

                }?>
```

Comment: `strtotime()` returns an integer. Get the differences, `$diff[]=abs($a-$b)`, and then find the smallest number, `min($diff)`. You will have to keep track of which diff belongs to which date, but that is just bookkeeping.

Comment: `'0'=> date('Y-m-d', $Date1),` should be `'0'=> date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date1)),`

Comment: @deceze and mark-barker How is this a duplicate question? As mentioned (If you read the question) I have this working with Hardcoded values, like in that other question, but not with duplicate values and im simple trying to find out why this is the case....

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this:

```
    <?php
    $day1 = '2015-01-01';
    $day2 = '2015-02-08';
    $day3 = '2015-03-13';
    $day4 = '2015-04-05';
    $day5 = '2015-05-27';
    $day6 = '2015-06-08';
    $day7 = '2015-07-19';  // YOU CAN ASSIGN DATE DYNAMICALLY

    $referenceDate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')); // REFERENCE DATE TO BE COMPARED


    $dates = array(
                0 => strtotime($day1),
                1 => strtotime($day2),
                2 => strtotime($day3),
                3 => strtotime($day4),
                4 => strtotime($day5),
                5 => strtotime($day6),
                6 => strtotime($day7),
            ); // FORM AN ARRAY 

    foreach($dates as $date) {
        $diff = $date - $referenceDate;

        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($diff);

        if($diff > 0){
            $resultArrFuture[$diff] = date('d-m-Y', $date);
        } else {
            $resultArrPast[$diff] = date('d-m-Y', $date);
        }
    }       
    // THIS WILL GIVE YOU CLOSEST DATE IN TWO DIFFERENT ARRAY ONE IS FOR FUTURE DATE OF REFERENCE ARRAY AND ONE FOR PAST 


    ksort($resultArrFuture);
    krsort($resultArrPast);

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($resultArrFuture);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($resultArrPast);

?>
```